# No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I want to open multiple file in python, and when I use 'with open' in code is show 'No such file or directory'
I don't know why.

Before I use 'with open' can show list name in directory.

```
for i in finders.find("home/view", True):
        for t in os.listdir(i):
            print(t)
```

But I use 'with open' it error

```
    for i in finders.find("home", True):
        for t in os.listdir(i):
            with open(t, "r") as f:
                test = f.read()
```

I expect the output show data in file. What should i do ?

Comment: What is `finders`? Try to `print(files)` before opening it to see what is actually in it.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that you're not trying to open a directory (or otherwise non-normal file) for reading? This may fail in a number of ways, depending on Python version and your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the folder path with `open`. The call to `os.listdir(app)` only gives filenames. You need to prepend those filenames with whatever path is in `app`.

```py
with open(f'{app}/{files}', 'r') as f:
```

Comment: How to do it ? I new python.

Comment: I've demonstrated one possible way to do it in the answer. My assumption is that `app` is the relative folder path to the file you want to open.

Comment: I can do it. Thank you very much :)